# Not able to clone/list TFS repo

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, git-tfs

Reading this doc I got an impression that I should be able to use git-tfs to get the contents of a TFS repo in order to clone some branches: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md

Tried these commands:

```
C:\Workspace.Git\Corp>git tfs list-remote-branches https:/scm.domain.com:8443/tfs
Given tfs name is not correct URI and not found as a registered TFS instance

C:\Workspace.Git\Corp>git tfs list-remote-branches https:/scm.domain.com:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection
Given tfs name is not correct URI and not found as a registered TFS instance

C:\Workspace.Git\Corp>git tfs list-remote-branches scm.domain.com
Given tfs name is not correct URI and not found as a registered TFS instance
```

where `https:/scm.domain.com:8443/tfs` is the server address which I use in Visual Studio 2012 to connect to TFS. It has `DefaultCollection` with several projects.

What is wrong with the server name I am supplying?

Comment: Didn't you forget a '/' for the 'https://' protocol in the uri?

Comment: Yes, I sure did!

Comment: @ajeh Have your issue been solved?  Make sure you could also be able to access the collection by `https://scm.domain.com:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection`  in your IE explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong url, lack of `/` and the **collection name**. Try this:

```
git tfs list-remote-branches https://scm.domain.com:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

***Will get the info like below screenshot***
[image]